# Authentication in hyperledger-composer app with OAuth2.0

Tags: oauth-2.0, hyperledger-composer

I have built a hyperledger-composer application (angular front-end, connecting to composer-rest-server), from which, so far, authentication is missing.

Here is what I understand:

1.) An identity needs to be issued for each participant in the network

2.) A business network card needs to be created for the identity created in step 1.)

3.) The business network card needs to be added to the wallet of the rest server

4.) steps 1.) and 3.) can be done by calling REST endpoints provided by the REST server

What I don't understand is this:

Let's say the REST server has in its wallet a business network card for "John Doe". The business network card contains the participant ID and the associated identity.

Google OAuth2.0 is used for authentication.

When John Doe wants to login to the hyperledger-composer app, he is redirected to google, where he is asked to type in his google account email + password.

If the business network card contained John Doe's google account email (or his google account password), then a connection could be made between the business network card and the user (John Doe) trying to log in. But the business network card does NOT contain any information from John Doe's Google Account (neither email nor password).

So how can the application know that the user trying to log in has a business network card and is therefore eligible to log in? As far as I can see it, all the application can know is that the user trying to log in has a google account - but this does not mean that he/she also has a business network card and is hence eligible to use the application.

Put differently: I don't understand how OAuth2.0 can help with authentication given that the OAuth2.0 provider does not save any data from the hyperledger-app (such as participant id or identity) and the hyperledger-app does not save any data from the OAuth2.0 provider (such as Facebook user name or Google Account email).

Answer (score 1):

Enabling OAth2.0 merely requires you to login first through your account before accessing the REST server, but does not actually connect to any wallet or participant. So it doesn't have too much use at this current state (in my opinion).

The workaround I've done is building a Node.js app with Passport and adding the desired authentication strategies, then when a user is created through Passport it also creates a participant on the composer-rest-server and links them.

Comment: but OAuth2.0 is also a Passport strategy (i.e. it's one of the passport implementations besides LDAP, and others) ... what authentication strategy did you use? How did you link the participant and the Passport user?

Comment: I used passport-local, but any auth strategy will work. Create a separate, standalone node app. Then install Passport.js. Create a route that registers the user, and then send that data to composer-rest-server POST route for the desired participant. Check out this github repo for an example: https://github.com/html5-ninja/hyperledger-vote-app

Comment: Thank you for your comment ... I looked at the application you linked to but - as far as I can see - that application does not use Passport.js ... Did you mistakenly link to the wrong app or am I not seeing something?

Comment: Another question: I developed an angular app ... authentication is to take place between the angular app and the rest server (which is a node.js application) ... So I would need an example of an angular app using passport local to authenticate to some server. Do you happen to know an example of this (i.e. angular app using passport-local for authentication)?